# unable to get Match property

Tags: excel, vba

I receive error '1004'
"unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"
on statement:

> "max_dat_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(max_dat,
> ws.Range("A3:A" & last_lin), 0) + 2"

I must have a blackout, because:
the 'max_dat' and 'last_lin' is found and shows in MsgBox(s) correctly. Then, I use these two values in the Match function but get the error '1004'.
I found plenty of similar issues in inet BUT cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. In the end I guess it's a very simple/stupid thing.

Any hint is appreciated,ed

```
Sub CopyRow()    ' right now I only want the 'Row#'

Dim last_lin As Long
Dim max_dat_row As Long
Dim max_dat As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")
last_lin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
MsgBox "last_lin: " & last_lin

max_dat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("A3:A" & last_lin))
MsgBox "max_dat: " & max_dat

max_dat_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(max_dat, ws.Range("A3:A" & last_lin), 0) + 2
MsgBox "max_dat_row: " & max_dat_row


MsgBox "The highest date is " & Format(max_dat, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " and its row number is " & max_dat_row
End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide sample data pls?

Comment: I think it 'prefers' to look for a number i.e. `CLng(max_dat)`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. With your and below suggestion I could solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

### Match a Date in VBA

- To match a date using the Match worksheet function in VBA, you need to convert it to a *Long* datatype.
- Whenever you need to use `Match` or `Max` (and a few other worksheet functions), it is smart to use their late-bound versions (i.e. to lose the `WorksheetFunction`) and to declare the variables as *Variant* datatypes. Then you can test their result. If you use `WorksheetFunction`, when an error occurs, it will be a run-time error and the code will stop.
- If you set the range, the code will become more readable.

[image]

**Short**

```vb
Sub MaxDateRow()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("A3", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        
    Dim MaxDate As Variant: MaxDate = Application.Max(rg)
    
    Dim MaxRow As Variant: MaxRow = Application.Match(CLng(MaxDate), rg, 0) + 2
    
    MsgBox "The latest date is " & Format(MaxDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") _
        & " and its row number is " & MaxRow & ".", vbInformation
    ' If the slash is not your date separator, you need to use "dd\/mm\/yyyy"!

End Sub
```

**Study**

- Here is a rewrite also covering some other issues.

```vb
Sub MaxDateRow()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("A3", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    If rg.Row < 3 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Referencing the range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ on sheet """ _
        & ws.Name & """.", vbInformation
        
    Dim MaxDate As Variant: MaxDate = Application.Max(rg)
    
    If IsError(MaxDate) Then
        MsgBox "The range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ on sheet """ _
            & ws.Name & """ contains errors!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf MaxDate = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No date found in range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ on sheet """ & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim MaxRow As Variant: MaxRow = Application.Match(CLng(MaxDate), rg, 0)
    
    If IsError(MaxRow) Then ' shouldn't be possible
        MsgBox "Could not find """ & CStr(MaxDate) & """ in range """ _
            & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ on sheet """ & ws.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MaxRow = MaxRow + 2
    
    MsgBox "The latest date is " & Format(MaxDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") _
        & " and its row number is " & MaxRow & ".", vbInformation
    ' If the slash is not your date separator, you need to use "dd\/mm\/yyyy"!

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanky you this clarifies my issues. All ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the type in declaration of `max_dat` from `Date` to `Long`.
With declaration as `Date` you can also use these variants:

```
max_dat_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(max_dat), ws.Range("A3:A" & last_lin).Value, 0) + 2
max_dat_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(max_dat), ws.Range("A3:A" & last_lin), 0) + 2
```